# why request.getParameter() giving me double decoded value

Tags: servlets, utf8-decode

I have a double encode GET Parameter. I am using `request.getParameter()`. The parameter is double encoded using UTF-8 encoding. Why am I not getting single encoded string. 
Eg.

```
param=%3D_Test%253Dtest
```

It should give me result as '=_Test%3Dtest'.
But what I am having is '=_Test=test'

Comment: Looks like a bug in container. Which container make/version are you using? Tried the latest version if any available?

Comment: I was using tomcat 7. I have figured it out a long ago. I don't even remember the case now, thanks anyway. I think that was php which was creating problems. While sending it to the container it was not encoding the request in UTF-8 some other format was there... Thanks anyway,..